# O pronome relativo está sendo usado corretamente?

Tags: português-brasileiro, pronomes

> Parece-nos importante insistir em que a leitura rigorosa de textos argumentativos se estende em exercícios de reconstrução do movimento expositivo, por meio **dos quais** o leitor acostuma-se a assumir a postura de um intérprete ativo da obra estudada.

O ‘dos’ é a preposição do pronome ‘quais’?

Ou ‘dos’ faz parte de uma locução prepositiva, ‘por meio dos’?

Se o correto for o primeiro caso, a preposição ‘dos’ corresponde à regência de qual verbo?

Comment: por meio de/da/do/das/dos: depende do antecedente, não do verbo: aqui o trecho 
"exercícios de reconstrução do movimento expositivo" [ufa] sería o antecedente.

Comment: Não sei se no Brasil seria semelhante, mas em Portugal aquele "se" deveria estar em próclise: "por meio dos quais o leitor *se acostuma*" (e não "*acostuma-se*").

Comment: ANeves, na norma-padrão do Brasil pronomes relativos são fatores de próclise, então, salvo engano meu, a ênclise acima é sinal de hipercorreção.